# Best Android threading technique for long-running tasks?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, memory

The thing is, that I have to keep a thread running for a pretty long time (it's really an indefinite time, could be 1 minute or even months), and it needs to update the UI about once every 1 milisecond...

There is the `Executor`, `AsyncTask`, `Handler` and the native `Thread` class... but which one is better for this case?

The problem with `AsyncTask` is that it is destroyed (or detached from the `Activity`?) like one hour or so after the `Activity` starts running on background, and the user could return to the `Activity` at any time just to find that it's not working (and even causing memory leaks), and the UI lags when changing to another activity or even pulling down the notification panel.

Natural Threads are even more laggy due to the `post()` method being called on the `TextView` every time I need an update to the UI (remember that I need to report progress about once every 1 milisecond)...

**tl:dr**
I'm developing a long running stopwatch, that can measure from miliseconds to days, weeks or even **years**. What is the best **UI-intensive** threading technique for this?

Could you please help me? Thanks!!

--- Edit:
Solved. It had to do something with system resources and the app moving to background. I just had to save the inital time and pauses as a bundle and load them when the app is started again. Thank you everyone!

Comment: 'update the UI about once every 1 milisecond' - you should find a way of easing up on that requirement.  Apart from the difficulty of handling UI input at that frequency,(no matter what inter-thread comms you use), human users cannot possibly assimilate data at that rate.

Comment: In your case the best one seems to be AsyncTask. do background stuff in doInBackground() and when you want to post the progress, use onProgressUpdate()

Comment: @MartinJames The timer updates the TextView inside a while() loop, that's why it updates it very fast, the frecuency is limited by the speed of the loop

Comment: @UmerFarooq That's what I'm currently using, but the system cancels (or unbinds from the Activity) the thread about one hour or so after the Activity passes to the background, and thats what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Android expert, but I'm guessing that the reason why your AsyncTask gets cancelled is because the OS, being a battery powered OS, is deciding that a long running background task is a bad thing for battery consumption.

Having your program run a background thread for years is going to be a big disappointment for your users who will wonder why their mobiles run out of juice within a couple of hours. I suggest finding another way of doing your time measurement. What's wrong with using the device's real time clock?

I see little point in trying to update a GUI once every millisecond. The OS isn't refreshing the screen at that rate anyway, and no user on earth is going to notice anyway. Plump for once every 40ms at most.

And then there's the matter of accuracy. There's no point trying to measure time with millisecond precision on a device like an Android mobile over periods of hours, never mind days or months. Left alone the clocks and oscillators will be wrong by several seconds a day. The best one will be the real time clock, but even that is going to be pretty poor (they always are). Android is probably doing an NTP updated a couple of times per day, so there will be brief periods in a day when the local clock is close to being accurate (but even then it won't be millisecond accurate).

So even if you do manage to measure time with millisecond precision over months the answers you'll be displaying to the user are going to be wrong by several seconds. You'll be lucky to get within minutes of the actual elapsed time.

If your goal is just to have a stopwatch display rapidly updating when the application is in the foreground, just loop reading the real time clock and calculate/display the time since the stopwatch was started. Don't bother doing anything in the background, just sleep. When your app becomes foreground again resume the loop; the device's real time clock will have been ticking away all the time you're app is asleep, allowing you to calculate and display the time difference. This will be a lot simpler than trying to have a long running background thread, and it will also be more accurate than any other way you might choose (though still not millisecond accurate).

Comment: Just a note that there are indeed classes of applications that do this type of data collection all the time. Data acquisition for process control is one, machine automation is another, medical monitoring is yet another. 
Now this user's data may not need to be displayed and updated every milli, but they still may need the data to be (eventually) displayed with millsecond precision and accuracy.
Just think, how would it look if you had to monitor a new type of medical pacemaker? It's just that kind of problem!

Comment: What David says is true...
I'm working on a project like the one he describes and this "stopwatch" is just like a test, but thats another story...

The thing is, that it displays a text string like a common running stopwatch (with ms presicion), and it must be running as long as the user wants it to (even years)...

Comment: @arielnmz, ok, so it sounds like you're trying to do something that I strongly suspect Android isn't well suited for from the point of view of power consumption. Doing anything once every millisecond over a long period of time is going to take some juice. Fine if you've got a mains supply! I'm afraid I don't know enough about Android and timers, but Linux has got some precision timer capabilities. You can do short nanosleep()s that are actually sleeps rather than a busy loop. Apply the PREMPT_RT patch and you'd even stand a chance of that working reliably. Dunno about Android though.

Comment: Doing reliable and guaranteed regular data capture is something that you either use a real time operating system for to run your acquisition loop and get the thread priorities right to make it reliable, or you build a device to do the data capture for you and have a device driver upload the data as and when its available. Either way I suggest that if possible you record a time stamp with every sample so that you can show that the data has been acquired correctly with no unwanted gaps.

Comment: @bazza well it really isn't a rsource intensive task, it just reads the rtc and calculates de delta between the start time and the current time (a simple substraction) and it sleeps the thread for 500 ms every cicle when the ms field is not visible.